# Error in the second bracket in C programming

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    double a,b,sum;

    printf("a= ");
    scanf("%lf",&a);

    printf("b= ");
    scanf("%lf",&b);

    sum=a+b;

    printf("%lf",sum);

    return 0;


}
```

Every time I run this code it shows error in second bracke. What is the error in this code?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Is the compiler picky about not seeing `int main(void)`? There might be a compiler option to insist on the correct definition and not to tolerate the obsolete `int main()`.

Comment: *Every time I run this code it shows error* **What** error?

Comment: Maybe there is a non-printable character at the end, copy and paste the code again in a new file and try again, or check it with hexdump command.

Comment: You should print a newline ('\n') after your output.